# PHP database rollback with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I am new in the MSSQL. i have create a database in MSSQL. Now all is working fine like add/edit/delete. i am adding 3 record in 3 different table at the same time in same of different database.
I want to use Rollback in the database. 
Suppose i am adding three record at the same time. First two work properly and last query find some issue in adding it in the table. At this time i want to remove the first two query which is inserted in the table.
can anyone help me for this issue ?

if you have another option to solve this issue then let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **sqlsrv_begin_transaction()** function to begin a transaction. Then, you can either commit it by calling **sqlsrv_commit()** function or roll it back by calling **sqlsrv_rollback()** function.

Example from [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-begin-transaction.php)

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}

/* Begin the transaction. */
if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}

/* Initialize parameter values. */
$orderId = 1; $qty = 10; $productId = 100;

/* Set up and execute the first query. */
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO OrdersTable (ID, Quantity, ProductID)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$params1 = array( $orderId, $qty, $productId );
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1, $params1 );

/* Set up and execute the second query. */
$sql2 = "UPDATE InventoryTable 
          SET Quantity = (Quantity - ?) 
          WHERE ProductID = ?";
$params2 = array($qty, $productId);
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2, $params2 );

/* If both queries were successful, commit the transaction. */
/* Otherwise, rollback the transaction. */
if( $stmt1 && $stmt2 ) {
     sqlsrv_commit( $conn );
     echo "Transaction committed.<br />";
} else {
     sqlsrv_rollback( $conn );
     echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: michalko just a little confussion. here you mentioned the first two query working properly then 3 query will execute. if there is a issue in the execution then first two will RollBack otherwise don't. I will fire 3 query at the same time. Any one of then will break then i want to Use RollBack for the Prevous Query.              For Example: suppose 3 query will not execute properly then first two will be Rollback. If second query will not execute properly then only first will be Rollback. If the first will now execute properly then no need to Rollback  because its a first query.